# How can i change the css class based on keywords in url with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the navigation bar as below

```
<ul>
  <li class="selected"><a href=">My Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="">xxxx</a></li>
  <li><a href="">mybook</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Photos <span>4</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="">Profile List</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want that if the url is  `www.abc.com/user/profile` then profile tab class should have class selected attached

If photos then photo tab.

If we can have partial match that will be good but i am not sure if thats possible

like in url i have `/user/book` and `myBook` gets selected

Comment: Are you asking about how to write a jquery selector for that? What about using something like `if ( .attr("href") == "your URL") { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some elegant variant:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a class="profile" href="/user/profile">My Profile</a></li>
  <li><a class="book" href="/user/book">My Book</a></li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function () {
  var page = document.location.href.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
  $('.menu .' + page).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to switch off of `location.pathname`. Granted that you give that `<ul>` a class of `nav`:

```
$(function () {
    if (location.pathname.search("/user/profile") != -1) {
        // page is /user/profile
        $("#nav li").eq(0).addClass("selected");
    } else if (location.pathname.search("/user/photos") != -1) {
        // page is some/thing
        $("#nav li").eq(3).addClass("selected");
    }
    ... etc
});
```

**Things to notice**

- We use `$(function () {...});` as opposed to `$(document).ready(function() {...});`. It is less typing and more efficient
- We use `String.search()`, which returns the *index* at which the string `"/user/profile"` appears. If the string is not found, `String.search()` will return -1, so if it `!= -1`, it exists.
- We also use `jQuery.eq( index )` this treats elements selected by a jQuery selector as an array and returns the element of the specified index.

**References**

Check out jQuery's `.eq` [here](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), and JavaScript's `String.search` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the part you want with regex:

```
var userPage = /user\/(.+)/.exec(location.href)[1];
```

That will give you the part after `user/`. Then you could use a `switch` statement:

```
switch (userPage) {
  case 'profile':
    ...
    break;
  case 'book':
    ...
    break;
}
```

Comment: can't i use anything like `if(href contains keyword) then return true` rather than splitting the urls